# Subdomain error with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I uploaded a .htacess file to hide the file extensions of my web pages - All was dandy until I used one of my subdomains... get.my-website.com - I got a 404 page.
It works when I put get.mywebsite.com/index.php

This is what I have in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you created a subdomain and added this `.htaccess` file to the document root of that subdomain?

Comment: I created a .htaccess file and added it to the public_html folder...

Comment: And is your sub domain pointing that that `public_html` folder?

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea...I uploaded the .htaccess file to the subdomain folder and it works now...Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly how it's supposed to work. ;) Glad you figured it out.